# Windows 7 drag&drop files onto the adress bar/directory path of the explorer (like in win8)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

I've been using windows 8.1 for the past years, and just installed windows 7 ultimate. However, I am missing a very convenient feature, which allowed me to drag n drop files into any directory that was a parent to my current folder.

[image: like so:]

In win 8.1, this would move the file to Program Files. However, in Win 7, it does nothing. Does anyone have suggestions or know a solution to get this to work in windows 7? 3rd party tools are ok, but if possible, I'd like to keep things as native and slender as possible, iykwim.

Edit: I should note that I do not want to use the directory tree on the left side, because that expands endlessly for directories with a lot of folders in them (of which I have quite a lot).
Of course, if this can be made to only expand to and show the current directory path, and not all the other folders within the directory path, I would use that, too. But the folder settings do not allow that - if I check "automatically expand to current folder" (that was a rough translation, i don't know what that option is called in english), it will still show all the other folders.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: update for free to Windows 10 and here you have this feature again.

Comment: Thanks, but I am no fan of windows 10, mostly due to their terms and conditions and privacy agreements (yes, I read those). I'm looking for a solution in win 7.

Comment: there is no native way to do it in Windows 7. You can disable the permissions entries in the settings app of Windows 10 and remove all store apps if you don't like them ;)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 collects information about you in countless ways and Microsoft is very far from being transparent about it. So I don't recommend you upgrade either. As for your questions, Windows 7 does not support that unfortunately (the same way it doesn't have an up-directory button in Explorer) These two minor improvements are actually the only things I like about Windows 10, otherwise it does not give me anything more than Windows 7, and Windows 7 is in fact faster.

Comment: Is it really faster? That's one of the things I heard mixed opinions about. Are there any benchmarks, or is it just perception? As for the rest, I agree that w10 doesn't add a lot that I need - I really like the explorer layout though (obviously) and I also prefer the task manager a lot. There are some other minor conveniences, too, but I'm still partial about upgrading, for the reasons you stated. If I could disable the data collection in the Home/Pro versions, though, I wouldn't hesitate to upgrade.

Comment: I have no complaints about the speed of Windows 10 (core i3-560, 8Gb RAM, Samsung EVO SSD) but when I recently went back to Win 7 I was suprised how much faster it felt immediately. The main reason I'm going back to 7 is because I can't trust this OS. It forces updates on you and it's obviously adding a lot of stuff I have no idea what. It recently installed a massive update that took about an hour, and I don't see ANY changes, I know it spies on us in many many way under the hood, I've disabled about 20 different things already, still I'm sure there's many more. It's all hooked up to ...

Comment: MS servers and constantly communicating with Microsoft no matter how many things you try to turn off, so I really cannot trust this OS, especially with the automatic updates MS can add any new ways of spying on us, and you cannot select updates like in Windows 7. I just feel it's a huge violation of my privacy.